# Variable name cannot be resolved to a variable error in Eclipse( Multiple inheritance)

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, compiler-errors

Getting the error of 
 y cannot be resolved to a variable 
 z cannot be resolved to a variable 
Line no.25 & 26

[image]

[image]

Comment: please include the code inside the quesiton and not as an image

Comment: Also to give you a short answer yet, your variables are called `m1` and `m2` and not `x` and `y`

Answer (score 1):

`y` and `z` are parameters of the constructor. There scope ends there, and they can't be used anywhere else. Instead, you should use the values you saved to `m1` and `m2` respectively.